# random character in file name while reading - java

Tags: java, random, character, text-files, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read a text file from a specific location. but at the end of file name the character is not decided.
Ex. it can be

```
Custom Summary Report -- UAT -- 2015-08-26d.txt
Custom Summary Report -- UAT -- 2015-08-26f.txt
Custom Summary Report -- UAT -- 2015-08-26.txt
Custom Summary Report -- UAT -- 2015-08-26c.txt
```

So, the last character can be any alphabet or no alphabet.

I am using scanner to read that text file. and in filepath I don't know what to pass as a string.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = new Date();

String filepath = "C:/Custom Summary Report -- UAT -- "+dateFormat.format(date)+X+".txt";


// creating File instance to reference text file in Java
File text = new File(filepath);

// Creating Scanner instance to read File in Java
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(text);
```

In the String filepath the character X is the character which can be anything. (ie-any alpahbet or nothing.)

So, the X which I have mentioned in String filepath can be anything which I don't know on a specific location. So I want to read that file. Since I don't know that character scanner is throwing an error.

I want a code which can take any character at that perticular place and can read a file.

Comment: What are you actually asking? Perhaps you're looking for `File.listFiles()`?

Comment: the X which I have mentioned in String filepath can be anything which I don't know on a specific location.

So I want to read that file.
Since I don't know that character scanner is throwing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've modified the solution and came up with this answer.

```
    File f = null;
    File filepath = null;
    File[] paths;


    try{      
       // create new file
       f = new File("C:/");

       DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = new Date();


       // returns pathnames for files and directory
       paths = f.listFiles();


       // for each pathname in pathname array
       for(File file:paths) {
          if(file.getAbsolutePath().contains("Custom Summary Report -- UAT -- "+dateFormat.format(date))) {
             filepath=file;
             System.out.println(filepath);
             break;
          }
       }
    }catch(Exception e){
       // if any error occurs
       e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // Creating Scanner instance to read File in Java
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(filepath);
```

Comment: I changed .startwith to .contains, and modified as per my question

Answer (score 2):

Try this: g will be the one you are looking for but it works only if there exists only one file you were looking for:

```
  File f = null;
  File g = null;
  File[] paths;

  try{      
     // create new file
     f = new File("c:/");


     // returns pathnames for files and directory
     paths = f.listFiles();


     // for each pathname in pathname array
     for(File file:paths) {
        if(file.getAbsolutePath().startsWith("C:/Custom Summary Report -- UAT -- ") {
           g=file;
           System.out.println(g);
           break;
        }
     }
  }catch(Exception e){
     // if any error occurs
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: @loenora, thanks it worked, I just changed .startwith to .contains and it worked. Thank You